# How to override parent schema field with discriminators using mongoosejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, schema

I have a parent schema Post:

```
{
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    authors: {
        type: [String],
        required: true
    }
 }
```

I want to make a child schema inheriting on this using the discriminator() mongoose function, but I want to add extra validation on the authors field to make sure the array it not empty.

How can I do this?

Also, could anyone point me to good documentation on mongoose discriminators. The official documentation hasn't been helpful in my search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this help you?

```
var Parent = mongoose.model('Parent', new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {...},
    author: {...}
}))

var Child = Parent.discriminator('Child', new mongoose.Schema({
    author: {
        default: ['something']
    }
}))
```

Just be aware that you have to include Parent before Child (apparently :o)

Comment: Ah ok so the parent attributes can just be overriden by child attributes?

Comment: Yes, you can either insert new fields or rewrite the whole field to other type

Comment: Be careful overriding fields, though.  If you find yourself overriding fields and changing types often in the discriminated classes, you may want to reconsider your design and maybe push the definition of that field to the "subclasses."